# Is it possible to auto-capture an image when a face is detected in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, face-detection, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am trying to create a face recognition login feature for my application.

Is there a way to make face detection live and have the app auto-capture a photo when a face is detected? Just so the user does not have to manually take a picture and check if a face has been detected.

Currently, my Xamarin.Forms app works this way:

- Click camera icon to open camera.
- Take a photo and send that photo to the Face API for face detection and to find a similar face.

Comment: You will need a constant face detection to trigger the take photo action.

Comment: @JamesWong, how do you accomplish the constant face detection feature using Azure Cognitive Services?